# Kaspersky GUI for Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, gui

Can You help me with this issue?It's possible to run Kaspersky on Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 0):

According to Kaspersky they don't list that they have an anti virus program for Linux.  They do list thought Endpoint Security for Linux.  The only thing that they don't list Ubuntu 13.04 as an acceptable product.  See [Kaspersky](http://www.kaspersky.com/products/business/applications/endpoint-security-linux) for more info.